# what would be the best choice for programming online store basket

Tags: php, shopping-cart

i have start to creating online store from scratch with PHP and everything is right but i need to know which way is better and safer for creating shopping cart(Basket)
1- work with session? ex: create session['cart'] and save products
2- work with database? ex: create a basket table and save products and after checkout delete everything from this basket
or maybe there is another way more better and simpler that i don't know

sorry for asking this question but i can't find good resource in internet,
thanks for yours Suggests

Comment: Do you really have to write it from scratch? If so, why? There are a lot of well-tested shopping cart solutions out there, and it will be quicker to learn how to use one than to write your own.

Comment: Try with some opensource projects like Opencart, Magento, OS Commerce, Drupal with Ubercart, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in fact three options:

- Cookies
- Sessions
- Database

---

Cookies are unsafe. If you save personal data in cookies, malware can easily read that data. You don't want to get your user in that kind of position.

Sessions tend to get deleted when a browser closes - even when it's accidentally. Safety is reasonable. Sessions use cookies to identify an user. A third user can copy that cookie and pretend to be that user.

The database seems to be the best bet so far, but how do you link a database record to a user?
My best bet is to have a database record linked to several (temporarily) constants. If you save IP address and a hash, which saved in a cookie too, you can identify a user even after his browser closes.

The cart will endure until you delete it, the cookie expires or the user changes IP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, where you store the items which a user is going to purchase is completely irrelevant.
I would recommend you stored them in cookies, so he user doesn't need a login to store his basket.

Unless you dont wan't hackers to spy on which product a user buys there is no need for encryption in this part.

But if you want to handle creditcards, you will need to create a https connection.

Comment: HTTPS is preferred anyway, because you could deal with very private products.

Comment: cookies? it's mean if user do not use cookies my basket will not work?